# RGTensor (Mathematica package) Print and Plot3D functions

Tags: computational-physics, software

I plot a function for a spherically symmetric metric in RGTensor package written for Mathematica and for pressure profile I obtain a complicated plot.

[image]

But then as I Print[] the corresponding pressure profile the value is zero which contradicts the resultant plot. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about physics.

Comment: Would [mathematica.se] or [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: There is no contradiction. The plot is essentially the zero-function - have a look at the axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially impossible to answer conclusively without more context, but unless you actually intended to plot a quantity that was of the order of a few times $10^{-16}$ (which is roughly where the machine-error threshold normally sits), then your plot is essentially the zero function, and there is no contradiction there.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I think you're right about the values on axes. But as I have had experience in plotting even smaller amounts which weren't zero this made me a little confused about this. And yes, I agree this question must have been asked in Mathematica page, sorry, I'm kinda new here. But again, thank you for answering.